# I dont know if my fan broken or thermal sensor is dying

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, sensors

Yesterday, everything still worked fine, my laptop running 24/7. Today CPU temp going 80 to 100*C (normal is around 50-65*C), so i know my fan is not spinning at all. But Windows is not crashed yet by overheat, after that i reset my pc and it say fan not found. Reset again and it booted into windows without problem, now the real problem starting

https://streamable.com/ocdi37

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUCTK.jpg

Comment: Your files are inaccessible.  You should upload them to imgur using the built-in capabilities of the editor.  It's not clear what your question is exactly.  **It sounds like your fan has failed and needs to be replaced.**

Comment: In the first video, the fan starts, stops, starts, stops much too quickly to be normal so the fan has died.  That is, it cannot run for any length of time.

Comment: Ramhound : both files still accessible.  
John : in HWinfo, it show fan RPM going from 1200 to 3500RPM, and i believe my laptop fan can't have that high RPM (same as one fan in my desktop)

Comment: I checked around. Laptop fans can indeed run that fast.  It says X230 tablet so it is a convertible. I have an X230 laptop here.

Comment: seem like my fan is dying, now i will order new fan and hope it work

Comment: right now it back to normal, this time i unscrew 8-90%, let it run with just few screws, weird

Comment: @CENA3 - I still cannot access those files, you really should upload the screenshot, using the method I suggested.

Comment: maybe your ISP blocked that website ? , i can access it without any problems

img: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mA6KXgnAQvUAyklqKyd7iw1_hR2mbSRm/view?usp=sharing
video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ewN_hYK4ApXqXYXOjHgRfqcnR_AgUJXg/view?usp=sharing

i think it happen when i'm moving laptop while it still on (and yep, not all screws in it own place) about 10 times, i heard a weird noise fan, but laptop still running ok so i dont care about it.

i'm already order new fan btw

Comment: mp3: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uTf_-gvltpJqaXpHBN8olFiwD6hpgO85/view now my fan running stabble like this, sometime it just have weird noise like first link, temperature around 45-60*C after i change thermal paste/add about 20-25 thermal pads into copper pipe. i can still feeling vibrate if i touch on any surface around fan area

i think ill try to put all screws left into it